# Simple calculator in Android Studio

Tags: java, beginner, android, calculator

I have been learning Java for a few months now and have created a basic calculator application in Android Studio for a school project. Since this is my first attempt at programming, I am sure that my code is not as succinct as it could be.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
double no1;
double no2;
double total;
char operator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btn0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn0);
    final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    final Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    final Button btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    final Button btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    final Button btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    final Button btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    final Button btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    final Button btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    final Button btnPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    final Button btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
    final Button btnMultiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);
    final Button btnDivide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);
    final Button btnEquals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEquals);
    final Button btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn0Text = btn0.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn0Text);
        }
    });

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn1Text = btn1.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn1Text);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn2Text = btn2.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn2Text);
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn3Text = btn3.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn3Text);
        }
    });

    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn4Text = btn4.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn4Text);
        }
    });

    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn5Text = btn5.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn5Text);
        }
    });

    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn6Text = btn6.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn6Text);
        }
    });

    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn7Text = btn7.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn7Text);
        }
    });

    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn8Text = btn8.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn8Text);
        }
    });

    btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btn9Text = btn9.getText().toString();
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + btn9Text);
        }
    });

    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            no1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
            operator = btnPlus.getText().charAt(0);
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            no1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
            operator = btnMinus.getText().charAt(0);
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            no1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
            operator = btnMultiply.getText().charAt(0);
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            no1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
            operator = btnDivide.getText().charAt(0);
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnEquals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            no2 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
            switch(operator) {
                case '+':
                    total = no1 + no2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    total = no1 - no2;
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    total = no1 * no2;
                    break;
                case '÷':
                    total = no1 / no2;
                    break;
            }
            editText.setText(Double.toString(total));
            no1 = 0.0;
            no2 = 0.0;
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: What do you want in answer? What are you expecting?

Comment: Some suggestions on how I can make my code more brief as a lot of it is just repeated code

Comment: Ok than AxelH's answer is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

**My review will mainly be readable code**

When you have lots of button, I am used to regroup the code in a single listener. This have the advantage to regroup the code in one place (but the inconvenient to have the code in one place ;) ). In general, I use the activity or the Fragment to implements the listener and manager itself the buttons.

In your case, you use the same logic for a lot of buttons (numerics to set the value). Why not use a logic that will works for all.

**Let's start step by step**

First step, I would use an array of Resource ID to recover the buttons to remove this big block of Buttons attribution.

```
int [] ids = {
   R.id.btn0,
   R.id.btn1
   R.id.btn2,
   R.id.btn3,
   R.id.btn4,
   R.id.btn5,
   R.id.btn6,
   R.id.btn7,
   R.id.btn8,
   R.id.btn9,
   R.id.btnPlus,
   R.id.btnMinus,
   R.id.btnMultiply,
   R.id.btnDivide,
   R.id.btnEquals,
   R.id.btnClear
}

//Loop on each ids.
for(int i : ids){
    //find the resource id by "i"...
}
```

Then, instead of using one listener per button, you use one listener (I use the Activity in this case but you could create a class). This means you don't need to store the Button in a variable, you set the listener directly like this :

```
for(int i : ids){
    ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this); //Like I said, my activity will implements ClickListener.
}
```

Then you regroup the code in the one method `onClick` and manage the code to execute by check the ID of the button (the view received).

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){ //the View will be the button clicked
        case R.id.btn0:
        ...
        case R.id.btn9:
        //then the cases for operators, and others...
    }
}
```

This means that all the calculating codes are in this listener, this is better than to have to scroll in a lot of lines just reading the signature of the methods ;)

This is of course just an esthetic choice. This doesn't improve performance.

The code will look like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private EditText editText;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int [] ids = {
          R.id.btn0,
          R.id.btn1
          R.id.btn2,
          R.id.btn3,
          R.id.btn4,
          R.id.btn5,
          R.id.btn6,
          R.id.btn7,
          R.id.btn8,
          R.id.btn9,
          R.id.btnPlus,
          R.id.btnMinus,
          R.id.btnMultiply,
          R.id.btnDivide,
          R.id.btnEquals,
          R.id.btnClear
        }

        for(int i : ids){
            ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this); //Like I said, my activity will implements ClickListener.
        }

        //Need this one since you need it later
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn0:
            case R.id.btn1:
            case R.id.btn2:
            case R.id.btn3:
            case R.id.btn4:
            ...
            case R.id.btn9:
                String text = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
                editText.setText(editText.getText() + text);
                break;
            //then the cases for operators, and others...
        }
    }
}
```

*For the code itself, I did not really check so I will leave other to do it ;)*

PS : I am open to suggestion, I tried to stay simple and explicit but I am still a beginner in Code Review ;)